# Dragging a children of a rotated element without taking the rotation into account while maintaining the rotation

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to solve this to no avail. I'm currently trying to drag a children of a parent with a rotation (transform: rotate(90deg)), but without taking the rotation axis of the rotated parent.

What I want to do is that if I drag the child element up, it drags the element to the right since the "Y" of the plane is to the right instead of up because it was rotated 90 degrees.

I made a quick fiddle to show this behavior attached below. It's made in jQuery since it was faster but I will use proper JS for the solution. Notice that you an drag the gray element up/down/left/right properly despite being rotated, but if you drag the red element up, it goes to the right instead of up, etc. I would like it to go up instead while keeping the rotation.

```
#parent {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background: grey;
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k71m9bfj/50/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/MartinGK/b97n248u/6/

I had to create a container for the child:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<h4>
Canvas
</h4>
    <div id="parent">
         <h4>Parent</h4>
  
        <div id="childContainer">
          <div id="child">
             <h4>Child</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and styled it with this:

```
#childContainer{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

`transform: rotate(-90deg);` to take back to the normal rotation.

```
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
```

And the rest of styling its for delimit the child's space that it can use.

You could add `transform: rotate(90deg);` to the child to keep the same rotation of the father. If you dont use it the child will use the `#childContainer`'s rotation.

Comment: Faced a similar problem, all doe i wish to do it without a other container that can be extended to any number of nested transformations: my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64169261/1008999