# Moving element with {n} nested transform

Tags: javascript, css, draggable, css-transforms

I got a container with unknown nested elements and I would like to move a selected child target around using js + transform translation. The problem I have is that a parent element can be scaled so the selected target moves faster/slower depending on the scale. And rotation makes it also harder to move it in the direction of the mouse movement.

How should I go about solving this problem? My assumption is that I need to walk up the DOM tree and combine all the matrixes and add, subtract values to figure out how much something needs to be moved. Eventually I need to also fix rotation support but i will deal with that later and maybe in another question.

But for now i have run into an error:

```
Error: Out of skills
   at <brain>:1:∞
```

```js
const target = document.querySelector('.target')
let init = null // Stores drag start event

target.onmousedown = evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  init = evt
}

// clear init event
onmouseup = () => init = null

// move the target around
onmousemove = evt => {
  if (init) {
    const x = evt.clientX - init.clientX
    const y = evt.clientY - init.clientY
    target.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
  }
}
```

```css
.nested {
    position: absolute;
    border: 4px solid #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 70px;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}

.nested.rotate {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.nested.scale {
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}

.nested .target {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px
}
html, body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.description {
    padding: 10px;
}
.target {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 150px;
    left: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ee8;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: translate(18px, -70px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="nested first">
        No Transform
        <div class="nested scale">
            scale(1.2, 1.2)
            <div class="nested rotate">
                rotate(30deg)
                <div class="target">Target</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **bug issue:** If you drag an element (x,y) inside a parent that has been previously rotated, then this.x and this.y values inside the onMove callback refer to horizontal and vertical directions, ignoring the fact that the parent is rotated.
> The result is that if, for example, you rotate the parent by 90deg, when you drag the child horizontally it moves vertically and viceversa.

Comment: Have you tried using an `opacity: 0` parent on the draggable element, where the parent is being dragged and the child is being rotated/scaled etc?

Comment: Opacity have nothing to do with moving only the target element. the problem i got is that it don't follow the mouse movement. I still want everything to be visible

Comment: You mean it doesn't follow the mouse movement after you rotate it right?

Comment: exactly, the target element don't move along with the mouse movement if a parent element is scaled or rotated - the target element don't have any rotation (it's inherited)

Comment: Where is `onmousemove` called? Is the snippet you added your full code?

Comment: Im having trouble to understand what exactly you want to accomplish tbh

Comment: This `onmousemove` event is right there (registered on the global window - just not prefixed with window, document or globalThis) it's a trimmed down (simplified) version of what I got in my project. The desired effekt I want to accomplish  is for my moving target element to follow the mouse movement like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht9supew). The problem with that one is that it uses top/left instead of translate(x, y), and the element isn't nested inside other elements like i want it to be. It should inherit all other transformations of the parents.